# Why does ActiveMQ in default configuration only use 70% percentOfJvmHeap

Tags: java, activemq-classic

The default configuration of ActiveMQ states in the [activemq.xml](http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html) file the following:

```
<beans>
 ...
    <broker>
       ...
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                 ...
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

What is or could be the reason to only use 70% of the JVM heap as memory limit instead of 100%?

Isn't this a waste of resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a rule of thumb to use `100 * (1 / sqrt(2))% ( == 70.7106781187%)` capacity of a system for a robust usage which would allow to survive sudden peaks in usage.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But how is the situation when this JVM is dedicated to ActiveMQ and already sized correctly with the `-Xmx` flag?

Comment: Suppose you agree it's a different question